# Obtaining node id and parent id in cypher or with neomodel

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neomodel

I'm using neomodel and I have the following models:

```
class ForumElement(StructuredNode):
    uid = UniqueIdProperty()
    created_at = DateTimeProperty(default=dt.datetime.utcnow())
    text = StringProperty()
    is_visible = BooleanProperty(default=True)

    picture = Relationship(Picture, 'HAS_PICTURE')
    author = Relationship(User, 'HAS_USER')


class Post(ForumElement):
    title = StringProperty(default="")
    latitude = FloatProperty()
    longitude = FloatProperty()

    tags = Relationship(Tag, 'HAS_TAGS')


class Comment(ForumElement):
    parent = Relationship(ForumElement, 'HAS_PARENT')
```

With that code I have in the database something like the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbGGW.png), where in blue we have "comments" and in pink we have "post".

Now, I would like to have as result of a query a list of couple <parent.uid, childen.uid>, how could I obtain that? Notice that the parent of a Comment could be a Post or another Comment

Answer (score 0):

On neo4j you can use a basic Cypher query like this:

```
MATCH(c)-[:HAS_PARENT]->(p)
RETURN c.uid, p.uid
```

Just `MATCH` according to the pattern of one relationship with label `HAS_PARENT` and `RETURN` only the uid properties.

When used with neomodel on python, it can be called like this:

```
query = '''MATCH(c)-[:HAS_PARENT]->(p) RETURN c.uid, p.uid'''})
results, meta = db.cypher_query(query, {})
```

You can test it on mock data like this:

```
MERGE (mark:COMMENT {uid: "Mark"})
MERGE (lju:COMMENT {uid: "Lju"})
MERGE (praveena:COMMENT {uid: "Praveena"})
MERGE (zhen:POST {uid: "Zhen"})
MERGE (martin:COMMENT {uid: "Martin"})
MERGE (mark)-[:HAS_PARENT]-(lju)
MERGE (lju)-[:HAS_PARENT]-(praveena)
MERGE (praveena)-[:HAS_PARENT]-(zhen)
MERGE (martin)-[:HAS_PARENT]-(zhen)
```